# Triangle Inequality proof with three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, triangles, absolute-value

> How do I prove $$|x + y+ z| \le |x|+|y|+|z|$$ without using the triangle inequality itself?

Are cases the best way to go? Or using properties of absolute? very stuck

Comment: Why won't you accept the proof $|x+y+z| \le |x+y| + |z| \le |x|+|y|+|z|$ via two applications of the triangle inequality?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Sometimes, a proof is so obvious that you just cannot see it if no one point it out.

Comment: As the $z=0$ case ***is*** the two-variable triangle inequality, you really can't avoid the triangle inequality in proving this.

Answer (score 4):

Because $$|x|+|y|+|z|=\sqrt{(|x|+|y|+|z|)^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+2|xy|+2|xz|+2|yz|}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(x+y+z)^2}=|x+y+z|.$$

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of two properties:

$\mathbf{1}.$ For some constant $k\geq0$:
$$|x|\leq k\iff-k\leq-x\leq k$$

$\mathbf{2.}$ For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, 
$$-|x|\leq x\leq |x|$$

The proof for the triangle inequality in three variables is as follows:

For $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$

Property $\mathbf{2.} \implies  \begin{cases} 
      -|x|\leq x\leq|x| \\
      -|y|\leq y\leq |y| \\
      -|z|\leq z \leq |z| 
   \end{cases}
$

Summing each inequality yields:

$$-(|x|+|y|+|z|)\le x+y+z\leq |x|+|y|+|z|$$

Property $\mathbf{1.}\implies |x+y+z|\leq|x|+|y|+|z|$